# emacs dired-jump key binding not work

Tags: emacs, dired

i write this in .emacs

```
(require 'dired-x)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") 'dired-jump)
```

but when i start emacs ,i can use M-x dired-jump ,but C-x C-j does nothing.I googled a lot,perhaps it is
the autoloading problem?anyone can slove it?

Comment: In general, keys of the form `C-c <letter>` are reserved for the user, so maybe use `C-c j` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dired-x` binds `dired-jump` by default, so if you have `require`d the library, you shouldn't need to add a binding (unless you wanted it on another key sequence, of course).

That said, I'm not sure why this isn't working for you, but try it without the `global-set-key` and see if it makes any difference?

Also test starting `emacs -Q`, entering `(require 'dired-x)` followed by <kbd>C-j</kbd> into the `*scratch*` buffer, and then testing whether <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> is bound.

Also check the value of the `dired-bind-jump` variable:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `dired-keys` <kbd>RET</kbd>

By default it's enabled, but when disabled that actually appears to *unset* a global binding if it exists, so depending on the actual order of execution, that might be undoing the binding you've set.

Comment: I find it,jabber use C-x C-j as prefix keys,conflict with this.Thank you.

Comment: Unless that's your own binding, you should contact the author and suggest that they change it to avoid the conflict.